# Is there a puppet_nist equivalent in chef?

Tags: chef-infra, puppet

I am wondering if there is anything similar to [puppet_nist](https://github.com/mcgonagle/puppet_nist/tree/master/nist/modules) in chef.
The closest I have come across is [dev-sec/os-hardening](https://github.com/dev-sec/chef-os-hardening/tree/master/recipes)

Answer (score 0):

That's the most I know of. We have InSpec compliance profiles for the CIS benchmarks and similar standards. There a few CIS cookbooks but nothing under very active maintenance that I've seen.